# XML parsing: How to separate same type siblings into different cells?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

XML file:

```
<books>
    <scifi key=...>
       <author>Don Larson</author>
       <title>The Edge</title>
       <year>...</year>
    </scifi>
    <scifi key=...>
       <author>Don Larson</author>
       <author>James Kiddleton</author>
       <author>Danny Wobers</author>
       <title>Incognitum</title>
       <year>1987</year>
    </scifi>
    <scifi key=...>
       <author>....</author>
       <author>....</author>
       <title>...</title>
       <year>...</year>
    </scifi>
    etc......................
</books>
```

XSL file:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <center><h1>SciFi</h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Authors</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="books/scifi">
      <xsl:sort select="year"/>
    <tr>
      <td><center><xsl:value-of select="title"/></center></td>
      <td>
       <xsl:for-each select="author">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td> 
      <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </center>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above table is displayed, for each cell containing a title, the cell next to it contains all the authors related to that title

eg:

```
    Title         Authors        Year
   (1cell)        (1cell)       (1cell)
    -----         -------        ----
                 Don Larson
 Incognitum   James Kiddleton    1987
                Danny Wobers
```

Now what I want to do is for each title display the authors (if there is more than one that is..) related to it in separate cells and get something like this instead:

```
    Title         Authors        Year
   (3cells)        (3cells)    (3cells)
    -----         -------        ----
 Incognitum      Don Larson      1987
 Incognitum   James Kiddleton    1987
 Incognitum     Danny Wobers     1987
```

Instead of having one cell for title and one cell containing all three authors related to that title, I want to have three cells with the same title and each of those cells can have a cell with the related author next to it.

I still want to keep sorting everything by yeat and I still want the order of my cells (left->right) to be Title->Author->Year

What do I have to change in my XSL file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want one row per author, so change

```
<tr>
  <td><center><xsl:value-of select="title"/></center></td>
  <td>
   <xsl:for-each select="author">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </td> 
  <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
</tr>
```

to

```
 <xsl:for-each select="author">
<tr>
  <td><center><xsl:value-of select="../title"/></center></td>
  <td>

    <xsl:value-of select="."/>

  </td> 
  <td><xsl:value-of select="../year"/></td>
</tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

David

Comment: Thanks, as you can see I've edited my questions and added a fragment of my html file, I want to apply the changes you suggestes through a jscript function only when the user clicks on a "author" button. I'm a bit lost when it comes to the changes I have to make in `setAttribute` etc... Any help on that?

Comment: I don't use that API but  .evaluate( is for evaluating xpath expressions in the source, you can't just extract random lines of a program and evaluate them out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <center><h1>SciFi</h1>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Authors</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="books/scifi">
        <xsl:sort select="year"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="author">
    <tr>
      <td><center><xsl:value-of select="../title"/></center></td>
      <td>
       <xsl:for-each select=".">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </td> 
      <td><xsl:value-of select="../year"/></td>
    </tr>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </center>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but in the long run I would suggest to move from one template doing it all with nested for-eachs to structured stylesheet with templates mapping each element type to a result and then doing apply-templates to keep going.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin, have a look at the comment I left David and tell me what you think.. :)

Comment: I think your original XSLT question has been answered and solved and you should post a new question tagged Javascript if you need help on that.

Comment: I followed you advice. Feel free to [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637998/javascript-function-that-modifies-xsl-my-variables-arent-working-properly) if you feel like helping me some more :) Thanks!